# Refresh table without reloading page and not losing css design

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, webforms

I know that this is already an issue over the internet but I have been researching for hours and not finding an answer that works for me. When I click the button, the text inside the textbox should be added inside the dropdown and reload the table without refreshing the whole page, I tried using update panel for it but when it does, the dropdown loses its bootstrap css. I have a code like this in ASP .NET

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>
                </asp:Label> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                Text="Clearance No."></asp:Label>
                </td>

                <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" Enabled="False">
                </asp:TextBox>
               </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="dropdown1" runat="server">
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" Enabled="true">
                   </asp:TextBox>
                <td>
                </td>

                <td>
                   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add To 
                   Dropdown" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
        </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
              <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" 
              EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
</UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say try researching AJAX, its a technique using Javascript to asynchronously send and receive data without refreshing the page

In ASP.net, JQuery is usually included in the default packages which makes using AJAX a lot easier.

Here is a sample request from some code I am working that refreshes a table:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Routing/GetRoutings',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: { PID: $(this).val() },
        success: function (data) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            $('#DOPT tbody').empty();
            $.each(data, function (index, data) {
                $('#DOPT').append('<tr><td>' + data.Operation_Number + ' - ' + data.Operation_Description + '</td></tr>');
            });
            $('#DOP').show();
            $('#NWO').show();
        },
        error: function (ex) {

        }
    });
```

I hope this was helpful